# How to save checkbox value in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am using checkboxes in Html and everytime I refresh my page, the checkboxes are unchecked again. How do I prevent this from happening ? Do I have to use JS ?
I tought about booleans fields but I don't really know how to implement them ...
I looked at other threads and it talked about javascript, but I do not understand anything at all about it, nor how to implement it.
Here is my code :

**views.py** :

'

```
@login_required(login_url='/login') 
def home(request):
check=False
MyToDo = Todo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
formtoDo = forms.TodoForm()


if request.method == 'POST' and 'todosub' in request.POST:
    
    formtoDo = forms.TodoForm(request.POST)
    if formtoDo.is_valid():
        todoit = formtoDo.save(commit=False)
        todoit.user = request.user
        todoit.save()
        
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home?')
    [...]
    data ={'form': form, 'formtoDo': formtoDo, 'MyToDo': MyToDo, 'check':check}
return render(request, "capygenda/entries.html", data)
```

'

**html** :

```
 <form method="POST", class="Entry">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <p>{{ formtoDo|crispy}} <button type="submit" name="todosub" >Add</button></p>
       
    
   </form>
   
   
       {% csrf_token %}
    
   {% for toto in MyToDo     %}
   
   <form method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
         <ul class="list">
           <li class="list-item">
             <input type="checkbox" class="hidden-box" id="{{ toto.id }}" autocomplete="off"/>
             <label for="{{ toto.id }}" class="check--label">
               <span class="check--label-box"></span>
               <span class="check--label-text">{{ toto }}</span>
             </label>
             <button class="button-24" role="button"><a href="{% url 'delete_todo' toto.pk   %}" class="delete">Delete</a></button>
         </ul>
       </form>
```

Comment: you have to use checkbox as "buttons", whenever I check box is marked a POST request needs to be sent to django backend.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. In your views, if the form is submitted i.e., when `request.method == 'POST'` is `True`, pass another parameter `{'checked: 'checked'}`:

```py
if request.method == 'POST' and 'todosub' in request.POST:
    
    formtoDo = forms.TodoForm(request.POST)
    if formtoDo.is_valid():
        todoit = formtoDo.save(commit=False)
        todoit.user = request.user
        todoit.save()
        
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home?')
    [...]

    # ---- here look at the last item ----
    data ={'form': form, 'formtoDo': formtoDo, 'MyToDo': MyToDo, 'check':check, 'checked':'checked'}

return render(request, "capygenda/entries.html", data
```

2. In your template, place that variable as an attribute in the `input` HTML element:

```html
 <input type="checkbox" class="hidden-box" id="{{ toto.id }}" autocomplete="off" {{ checked }}/>
```

This way, the `checked` attribute of the input will be dynamically placed. If it was passed via `POST` method, you have it. Otherwise, it's just empty.

Comment: Hello, I tried your method and I'm sorry, but my every time I refresh my website, it makes the checkboxes checked and even if I uncheck one, when I refresh It's checked again

Answer (score 0):

add `checked` in the input field if you want it to keep it pre-checked or dependent on View values.

```
<input {% if checked %} checked{% endif %}"/>
```